# closest point on a box to a line

Tags: math, geometry

[image]

I have drawn a 2D representation of the problem, but I will eventually have to solve this in 3 dimensions.

A line is drawn from an origin point to infinity, in a direction given by pitch and yaw. There is an axis-aligned box "in front of" the point.

I want to get the coordinates of the point on box that is closest to the line, or, if it intersects, closest to the origin point.

I.e., if the line were 'turned' towards the box, which point of the box would intersect with the line first?

Comment: would the intersection point always be on a corner (if the line isn't intersecting)?

Comment: What does axis aligned mean?

Comment: @MadPhysicist it's edges are parallel to the coordinate axes

Comment: @thebjorn yeah it would (in 2 dimensions, in 3 dimensions it would be on a "corner" but not necessarily a vertex)

Comment: I'm guessing you can transform the coordinate system so the origin is at (0,0,0) and the line is at the x-axsis and then find the x-value corresponding to the minimal y-value of the box. You might get better answers at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry / mathematics instead of programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Make parametric represenation of the ray with base point `P0`, direction vector `D` and parameter `t`

```
P = P0 + t * D
```

Get t for intersections of the ray with rectangle edges like this (similar in 3d):

```
Rect.Right = X0 + t * D.X
```

Find what intersection occurs first (smaller t), check coordinates of intersection. If inside edge - point found. If not, analyze intersection parameters with edgr continuations to determine what corner (perhaps edge in 3d) is the closest

Note that in 2d case you need to check only two possible edges - depending on ray direction. For example - left and bottom for your right picture. When you see that  intersections are out of edges - check what of two corners is closer. The same for 3d - but intersection is possible for three faces and closest for more edges or corners.

Comment: Isn't that extremely inefficient? I have to iterate x hundred thousand times with different `t`

Comment: For 2d you can check whether corners lie at the same side relative to the line (very fast with cross product). But it is not applicable in 3d. Consider line clipping algorithms (Cohen-Sutherland, Liang-Barski etc). All require significant work in 3d. Proposed approacj resenbles  Amanatides-Woo algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Let the position of the point be `(x0,y0,z0)` and the box have corners `(x1,y1,z1)` and `(x2,y2,z2)` with x1 < x2, y1 < y2, z1 < z2. In terms of yaw ψ and pitch θ a unit vector along the line will be give by

```
(u,v,w) = (cos ψ sin θ, sin ψ, cos ψ cos θ)
```

The line is `(x0,y0,z0) + t (u,v,w)`

Finding intersection with one of the plane containing a face of the box is trivial. Say to find the intersection with the plane x=x1, just requires solving 
`x0 + u t = x1`  so `t = (x1-x0)/u`. Once found its easy to check if the intersection is contained in the face.

The tricky situation happens if the line does not intersect the faces. Here we have a pair of [skew lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines#Distance), and wish to find the closest pair of points one on each line.

Consider the closest point to the edge from (x1,y1,z1) to (x2,y1,z1).

We want to find the parameter s,t such that that the points

```
(x0,y0,z0)+s(u,v,w)
(x1,y1,z1)+t(1,0,0)
```

are the closest. The segment joining these points must be perpendicular to both lines. A vector along that line is the cross product

```
N = (u,v,w) X (1,0,0) = (0,w,-v)
```

Now consider the plane through (x1,y1,z1) spanned by (1,0,0) and N,  this has normal

```
N2 = (1,0,0) X N
   = (1,0,0) X (0,w,-v) 
   = (0,v,w)
```

and the plane is defined by

```
P . N2 =  (x1,y1,z1) . N2
```

Take a point on our ray

```
( (x0,y0,z0)+s(u,v,w) ) . N2 =  (x1,y1,z1) . N2
(x0,y0,z0) . N2 + s (u,v,w) . N2 = (x1,y1,z1) . N2
s (u,v,w) . N2 = ((x1,y1,z1)-(x0,y0,z0)) . N2
s (v^2+w^2) = (y1-y0) v + (z1-z0) w
```

so

```
s =  [ (y1-y0) v + (z1-z0) w ] / (v^2+w^2)
```

We can repeat the above for each edge on the box, find the closest points and select the smallest.